# Why can't I replace option value?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to modify the displayed option values on this page (click "More Options" to expand parameters:
https://jobs.sap.com/?utm_source=careersite&utm_campaign=Top_Button

However, it appears that for some reason I cannot change the values for any of the options, only for the placeholder value. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
$("#optionsFacetsDD_department option").text($("#optionsFacetsDD_department 
option").text().replace("Administration", "Admin"));
});
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're using `$("document")`, which is telling jQuery to find a `<document />` element in the DOM - which will never exist, instead of `$(document)`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#optionsFacetsDD_department option").text($("#optionsFacetsDD_department option").text().replace("Administration", "Admin"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="optionsFacetsDD_department">
  <option>Foo Administration</option>
</select>
```

Also note that you can improve the code by providing a function to `text()` which accepts the current text value as an argument. You can then call `replace()` on that without having to access the DOM once more to get the text of the element which you already have a reference to. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#optionsFacetsDD_department option").text((i, t) => t.replace("Administration", "Admin"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="optionsFacetsDD_department">
  <option>Foo Administration</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! It also looks like there is an issue with the select element only getting populated after page load and therefore the change doesn't take effect on document load. Can I somehow trigger the renaming to happen only once options are present?

Comment: Yes - put this logic inside the callback/promise of the AJAX request which populates the `option` elements in the DOM - at least, I presume you're using AJAX for this

Comment: I was able to control it using .ajaxComplete - I only have access to the header. Thank you again!